# How to properly load images to Canvas in React

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I have an array of image urls. I want to display one image at a time on canvas. I've setup useEffect to be triggered when index of current image is changed.

I've researched online and found out that images load async and i must use onload callback to draw new image on canvas ([Why won't my image show on canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873679/why-wont-my-image-show-on-canvas)).

I've setup effect and callback like this:

```js
const [image, setImage] = useState<HTMLImageElement>()

useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image()

    image.onload = () => update

    image.src = images[imageState.imageIndex]?.url

    setImage(image)
}, [imageState.imageIndex, images, update])

const update = useCallback(() => {
    if (!canvasRef.current) return

    const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d')

    if (!ctx || !image) return

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height)

    canvasRef.current.width = image.width
    canvasRef.current.height = image.height
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)
}, [image])
```

canvas is setup like this:

```js
export const ImageGallery = (props: ImageGalleryProps) => {
    const classes = useImageGalleryStyles()

    return (
        <div className={classes.outerContainer}>
                <canvas
                    style={{
                        left: `${imageState.position.x}px`,
                        top: `${imageState.position.y}px`,
                        transform: `rotate(${imageState.rotate}deg) scale(${imageState.scale})`,
                    }}
                    ref={canvas.ref}
                    className={classes.image}
                />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Images are changed like this:

Callback never called and canvas remains blank. What is proper way to update canvas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with this:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const image = new Image()

        image.onload = function() {
            if (!canvasRef.current) return

            const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d')

            if (!ctx || !image) return

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasRef.current.width, canvasRef.current.height)

            canvasRef.current.width = image.width
            canvasRef.current.height = image.height

            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0)

            coordinates.map(c => {
                switch (c.coordinates.$type) {
                    case DefectCoordinatesType.WideSide:
                        c.coordinates.WideSides.map(ws => {
                            if (image) {
                                ctx.beginPath()
                                ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false

                                ctx.moveTo(ws[0].x * image.width, ws[0].y * image.height)
                                ctx.lineTo(ws[1].x * image.width, ws[1].y * image.height)

                                ctx.closePath()
                                ctx.strokeStyle = 'red'
                                ctx.lineWidth = 2
                                ctx.stroke()
                            }
                        })
                }
            })
        }

        image.src = images[imageState.imageIndex]?.url
    }, [checkBoundaries, coordinates, imageState.imageIndex, images, prevIndex, zoomOut])
```